# Как остановить передвижение метки используя Checkbox

Tags: c#

Делаю лабу по программированию в вузе, нужна помощь.
Метка Label движется по краям формы по часовой стрелке. При отмеченном Checkbox на второй форме метка должно двигаться а при неотмеченном должна стоять на месте.

public partial class Form1 : Form

```
{




    enum Direction { Right, Down, Left, Up };
    Direction direction = Direction.Right;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Right:
                label1.Left += 10;

                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                label1.Top += 10;
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                label1.Left -= 10;
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                label1.Top -= 10;
                break;
        }
        if (label1.Left > ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width)
        {
            direction = Direction.Down;
            label1.Left = ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width;
        }
        if (label1.Top > ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height)
        {
            direction = Direction.Left;
            label1.Top = ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height;
        }
        if (label1.Left < 0)
        {
            direction = Direction.Up;
            label1.Left = 0;
        }
        if (label1.Top < 0)
        {
            direction = Direction.Right;
            label1.Top = 0;
```

Подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Comment: `if (checkBox1.Checked){ //Do something }`, либо вообще выход из метода `if (checkBox1.Checked) return;`. Ну а вообще, вы сами хоть что то пробовали? Как нам по представленным данным узнать как и что у вас там работает и что конкретно вы хотите?

Comment: if (checkBox1.Checked){ //Do something } Это то понятно, как именно заставить её остановиться, главный вопрос.

Comment: Ну а что у вас запускает? Нам же это не известно. У вас ведь есть то, что вызывает вашу логику, так? Я вижу к примеру `timer1_Tick`, значит у вас есть где то таймер, у таймеров обычно есть методы Start/Stop, значит делайте `timer1.Stop();`.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо.